# How do I make jigsaw run in windows 10 ?

Tags: java-platform-module-system, cmder

$ ./vendor/bin/jigsaw init

When I type that on my terminal (cmder), I get a

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

error

Answer (score 2):

I was too using CMDER to initialize the Jigsaw files.

I don't know why the CMDER can't initialize the files but when I changed the terminal to GitBash, it was working.

I think this is because the GitBash terminal uses the **$** sign and CMDER uses lambda **(λ)** sign. This is just a theory. I am still not sure.

Change the cmd line and just do this from your directory.

Example - directory is a blog

```
cd blog
vendor/bin/jigsaw init
```

A message will be flashed :

```
Your new Jigsaw site was initialized successfully.
```

Done!

You don't have to touch the files in the composer directory.

Answer (score 1):

replace the `/` with `\`

like this `./vendor/bin/jigsaw init`

to

`.\vendor\bin\jigsaw init`

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can try and use:

> C:\Users\"COMPUTER NAME"\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\jigsaw

this should work - let me know if it doesn't. Also have you tried the command without the '.' like so:

> /vendor/bin/jigsaw init

to be honest option 1 is your best best.